# Weird syntax error in draughts game

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

I began progamming with Python two months ago and I encountered a problem a week ago and cannot find a solution.
I have drawn a draughts game's board, and I want the pieces to move as I want them to.

Here are two functions, direction_rouge() (rouge is red in French) et direction_bleu() (bleu means blue).

They change pieces coordinates properly, I tried to use them out of the next If loop.
The loop determines the number of turns, during which players can play.
Each loop is a turn, so that direction_rouge() and direction_bleu() are called once (two if a piece is eaten by another).

I cannot find the Syntax Error that occurs on the function call each turn.

Here is the programm, have fun ^^ :

```
def direction_rouge() :
        """1 up left on the board
        2 up right
        3 down left
        4 down right"""

        t.up()
        t.color(255,255,255)
        t.goto(Xrouge[r-1],Yrouge[r-1])
        t.down()
        t.goto(Xrouge[r-1],Yrouge[r-1])
        t.up()
        t.color(255,0,0)

        if n == 1 :
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]-50,Yrouge[r-1]+50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]-50,Yrouge[r-1]+50)
                Xrouge[r-1] = Xrouge[r-1]-50
                Yrouge[r-1] = Yrouge[r-1]+50
        if n == 2 :
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]+50,Yrouge[r-1]+50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]+50,Yrouge[r-1]+50)
                Xrouge[r-1] = Xrouge[r-1]+50
                Yrouge[r-1] = Yrouge[r-1]+50
        if n == 3 :
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]-50,Yrouge[r-1]-50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]-50,Yrouge[r-1]-50)
                Xrouge[r-1] = Xrouge[r-1]-50
                Yrouge[r-1] = Yrouge[r-1]-50
        if n == 4 :
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]+50,Yrouge[r-1]-50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xrouge[r-1]+50,Yrouge[r-1]-50)
                Xrouge[r-1] = Xrouge[r-1]+50
                Yrouge[r-1] = Yrouge[r-1]-50
        t.color(255,255,255)
        t.write(r,False,align = "left",font=("Arial",10,"normal"))



def direction_bleu() :
        """same as direction_rouge"""

        t.up()
        t.color(255,255,255)
        t.goto(Xbleu[b-1],Ybleu[b-1])
        t.down()
        t.goto(Xbleu[b-1],Ybleu[b-1])
        t.up()
        t.color(0,0,255)

        if n == 1 :
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]-50,Ybleu[b-1]+50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]-50,Ybleu[b-1]+50)
                Xbleu[b-1] = Xbleu[b-1]-50
                Ybleu[b-1] = Ybleu[b-1]+50
        if n == 2 :
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]+50,Ybleu[b-1]+50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]+50,Ybleu[b-1]+50)
                Xbleu[b-1] = Xbleu[b-1]+50
                Ybleu[b-1] = Ybleu[b-1]+50
        if n == 3 :
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]-50,Ybleu[b-1]-50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]-50,Ybleu[b-1]-50)
                Xbleu[b-1] = Xbleu[b-1]-50
                Ybleu[b-1] = Ybleu[b-1]-50
        if n == 4 :
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]+50,Ybleu[b-1]-50)
                t.down()
                t.goto(Xbleu[b-1]+50,Ybleu[b-1]-50)
                Xbleu[b-1] = Xbleu[b-1]+50
                Ybleu[b-1] = Ybleu[b-1]-50
        t.color(255,255,255)
        t.write(b,False,align = "left",font=("Arial",10,"normal"))






# Déroulement de la partie (the game's sequence of events)



turns = int(input("maximum number of turns :"))

t.width(30)

for i in range(1,turns+1) :

        # Red player's turn

        r = int(input("pion rouge numéro : "))
        n=int(input("direction =")
        direction_rouge()

        for i in range(0,15) :    #checks if there was another piece on the board

                if Xrouge[r-1]==Xbleu[i] and Yrouge[r-1]==Ybleu[i] :
                        t.color(255,255,255)
                        t.begin_fill()
                        t.circle(15)
                        t.end_fill()
                        t.color(255,0,0)
                        direction_rouge()
                        #Xbleu[i]=0
                        #Ybleu[i]=0

        t.color(255,255,255)
        t.write(r,False,align = "left",font=("Arial",10,"normal"))

        # Blue player's turn

        b = int(input("pion bleu numéro : "))
        n=int(input("direction =")
        direction_bleu()

        for i in range(0,15) :       #same role
                if Xbleu[b-1]==Xrouge[i] and Ybleu[b-1]==Yrouge[i] :
                        t.color(255,255,255)
                        t.begin_fill()
                        t.circle(15)
                        t.end_fill()
                        t.color(0,0,255)
                        direction_bleu()
                        #Xrouge[i]=0
                        #Yrouge[i]=0

        t.color(255,255,255)
        t.write(b,False,align = "left",font=("Arial",10,"normal"))



print("La partie est finie. (The game is over)")
```

Comment: You didn't paste the error's line and message.

Comment: In which function does the error occur? Could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Include error message please, we are not clairvoyant.

Comment: Actually, I see you have `t.width(30)` but no `t` is defined.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I think it doesnt matter, `t` can be defined outside of this code

Comment: Here is the real problem : **direction_rouge()** is highlighted in the turn sequence of events. And t always refers to turtle. I thought I mentioned it, sorry. Thank you for your fast answers ! :)

Answer (score 3):

This line has unbalanced parentheses. This is causing a syntax error when it read the first token of the next line.

```
    n=int(input("direction =")
```

The fix is to add a close parenthesis:

```
    n=int(input("direction ="))
```

This error appears twice in your code. It must be fixed in each location.